# load json of data into vuex store and access in component

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs2

I am trying to load a JSON file of content into my vuejs app and accessing it in my components. I am able to load the json into the vuex store by creating an API:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const Http = new Vue();

export function getData() {
  return Http.$http.get('./app/assets/content/en_uk.json')
    .then(response => Promise.resolve(response.data))
    .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
}
```

and an action

```
export const getSiteContent = ({commit}) => {
  api.getData().then(data => {
    commit('siteContent', data);
  });
};
```

I run getSiteContent on created function of the main vue instance

```
export default new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  store,
  router,
  created() {
    getSiteContent(store);
  },
  render: h => h('router-view')
});
```

using the vue debug tool in chrome i can see the store

```
export const state = {
  isSearching: false,
  searchQuery: '',
  siteData: {},
  filteredComponents: [],
  hasResults: false,
  activeComponent: null
};
```

gets updated with the siteData.

This is part of the json:

```
{
  "global": {
    "project_name": {
      "text": "Project title"
    },
    "search": {
      "form_placeholder": {
        "text": "Search..."
      },
      "no_results": {
        "text": "Sorry no results for '{0}' was found"
      },
      "search_text": {
        "text": "You are searching for '{0}' and there are {1} found"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try and access

```
computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['siteData']),
      mumbo () {
        return this.siteData.global.project_name;
      }
    }
```

in my component like `{{mumbo}}` I get cannot read property of project_name of undefined.

I feel like this is a time issue as it doesn't fall over when I set it to return siteData.global

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or I am missing a connection to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed the problem here is that Vue is trying to access the contents of `siteData` for that computed property while the data is still loading. Although `siteData` is a valid object initially, trying to access `siteData.global.project_name` fails because `siteData` has no field `global` when the data hasn't loaded yet. To prevent the error, you will have to include a check like this:

```
mumbo () {
    return this.siteData.global ? this.siteData.global.project_name : 'Loading...';
}
```

To illustrate the solution, here's a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dexng1o/) based on your code.

Comment: Thanks for this, i have tested and this works. I'm just wondering is there other ways round this? or am i doing everything how it should be done?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a good pattern and the way it should be done. An alternative would be to load the data before the Vue component is initialized, but usually something like that is a lot more complicated...

Comment: If I wanted to load the data before the component has loaded could you point me in the direction of what to look at please

Comment: I suppose there are many ways of doing this, but probably the simplest one is using `v-if` to prevent rendering of the entire component until the data has loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/55jabLq8/

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddle. I will look more into this and try it.